# android gstreamer ndk-build .o incompatible target

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, gstreamer

I try to build android project with GStreamer - using NDK on Windows.
But have a lot of error, like this:

```
Error:error: C:/gstreamer/lib/gio/modules/static/libgiognutls.a(gtlsbackend-gnutls.o): incompatible target
Error:error: C:/gstreamer/lib/gstreamer-1.0/static/libgstlibav.a(libgstlibav_la-gstav.o): incompatible target
```

and then

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Project is sample - get from github:
https://github.com/jaroslavas/Gstreamer-Android-example

I`m just beginner in android - what this errors means?
And how I can fix them?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you will have errors like this, it means, than you need change platform in Application.mk(jni folder). For Windows it was:

```
APP_ABI := x86
```

Also I change NDK to version r9d NDK.